# Program with a memory leak on purpose?

Tags: memory-leaks

For a presentation about memory leaks, i'd like to present a program where a memory leak could be easy to do, and would have visual effects; how could i do this ?

I don't want to use any language in particular, even if C, java or Python would be prefered.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: I'd like something that could fill up the memory of a virtual machine ? so i could show how the remaining RAM gets lowered again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would produce memory leaks in your system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char *c;
    for(;;)
    c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exaclty the kind of things i wanted; short code so it's easy to understand for the people watching. Thanks again !